# What stops Musk from changing Tesla's incorporate location to find judges that would rule in his favor

Tags: united-states, corporate-law, incorporation, federalism

Recently, a judge in Delaware [ruled in favor of shareholders and blocked Elon Musk's compensation package](https://www.cnbc.com/2024/01/30/tesla-shares-slide-after-judge-voids-elon-musks-56-billion-compensation.html).

Later, Elon Musk said he would try to incorporate Tesla in Texas:

"Tesla and Mr. Musk could appeal the court decision. Mr. Musk on Thursday said he would seek to incorporate the company in Texas, a state that he believes could be more hospitable to businesses." [Source](https://www.nytimes.com/2024/01/31/business/tesla-elon-musk-pay-package.html).

What stops Elon Musk or any CEO from constantly changing place of incorporation if judges don't rule in their favor?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Short Answer

> What stops Elon Musk or any CEO from constantly changing place of
> incorporation if judges don't rule in their favor?

Nothing other than the need for approval from the board of directors, which is almost certain to be freely given if it is asked to do so.

#### Long Answer

###### He Can Move The Company

The company certainly can be incorporated in a different state, going forward, assuming that the company's board of directors will agree with the move. As a practical matter, in businesses like this, the board of directors almost surely would approve the change if their CEO asked for it. Corporate boards of directors are very loyal to the management team in the U.S.

A move from Delaware to Texas would probably result in a medium sized one time hit to the company's stock price (which might cost him a few billion dollars on paper), because Wall Street considers Delaware a preferable place to incorporate a big business. But, as the case of the Twitter acquisition by Mr. Musk illustrates, Mr. Musk seems to be unconcerned about making decisions that hurt the stock prices of companies that he owns.

###### A Move To Texas Would Only Have Prospective Effect

Mr. Musk can't do anything to change the venue of the pending lawsuit. The corporation was incorporated in Delaware when the acts in question happened, so Delaware is the proper choice of law and venue for the case. There is no other place that these issues could be litigated. And, he can't have this case dismissed without the consent of the shareholder plaintiffs, who would never do so.

Also, assuming that the decision is affirmed on appeal by the Delaware Supreme Court, this decision can't be re-litigated anywhere else, under the doctrine of *[res judicata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Res_judicata)*. And, any findings of fact or law that were decided against Mr. Musk in this case can't be re-litigated in a new forum, under the doctrine of [collateral estoppel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collateral_estoppel).

For example, the Delaware court's factual finding that the Compensation Committee members that made the 2018 were not independent directors is something that would be binding against Mr. Musk in any new case in Texas that arises after the change of corporate forum and involves the same directors.

Indeed, any new cases over the internal corporate affairs of his company prior to a move to a new state in 2024 would still be governed by Delaware law, not Texas law, under general choice of law considerations. And, the case would probably be litigated in the Delaware courts, despite the fact that company relocated itself to Texas, under general jurisdictional principles applicable to civil cases.

###### Relocating To Texas Is Probably Foolish

As irritated as Mr. Musk may be with the Delaware Court of Chancery, however, as a result of his latest big loss in its courts, moving his company to Texas would probably be a self-defeating move.

> What do 68% of Fortune 500 companies and 93% of all U.S.-based initial
> public offerings have in common? They’re all registered in Delaware[.]

([Forbes](https://www.forbes.com/advisor/business/incorporating-in-delaware/) source)

Delaware is a popular place of incorporation for big businesses for a reason. The substantive corporate law in Texas is [less pro-management](http://www.businesslawpost.com/2013/02/) than the substantive corporate law is in Delaware.

Mr. Musk lost this case, despite the fact that Delaware is a very unfavorable forum for shareholder plaintiffs (although [some commentators](https://frostbrowntodd.com/the-yin-and-the-yang-of-delaware-corporate-law/) espouse the minority view that Delaware is more pro-shareholder than other states in the rare cases when shareholders have a really solid case), because he was so clearly in the wrong. He arranged a pay package for himself that was an order of magnitude (one comment to this post suggests *three orders of magnitude*) greater than comparable companies that were playing by the rules. He had his pay package approved by directors whose lack of independence was concealed from the shareholders. Mr. Musk would have fared no better in this case in a Texas court, although it would have taken perhaps a year or two longer to get to that outcome.

Delaware courts routinely dismiss shareholder lawsuits at the outset, with only modest cost to the corporation, [in the vast majority of shareholder lawsuit cases](https://frostbrowntodd.com/the-yin-and-the-yang-of-delaware-corporate-law/). Texas courts would screen out weak shareholder lawsuits at the outset far less often. This would expose Mr. Musk to more shareholder litigation and more shareholder litigation risk.

There are downside to a move to Texas in addition to differences in the substantive law.

Texas handles big dollar corporate law cases much more slowly than Delaware does.

> Instead of a traditional trial system, corporate lawsuits in Delaware
> are resolved by the Court of Chancery, a court made up of judges who
> specialize in corporate law. Because of this, Delaware has
> well-developed and predictable legal precedents that may benefit
> corporations. While the average civil lawsuit may take a number of
> years to resolve, Delaware’s use of judges instead of juries and
> prioritization of corporate-related cases means similar cases can be
> decided more quickly.

([Forbes](https://www.forbes.com/advisor/business/incorporating-in-delaware/) source)

Texas has judges have less expertise in this subject area, which could prevent Mr. Musk from utilizing procedural protections of his legal rights, because Texas judges don't understand the importance of the case management standards and processes that Delaware judges routinely apply in these cases.

Texas corporate law litigation outcomes are also much less predictable, because Texas has much less case law on the relevant legal issue. But, admittedly, this could be a plus if you anticipate that you are usually going to be in the wrong and breaking the law in the future.

###### The Tax Benefits Of Delaware Law Are Overblown

Many popular descriptions of the benefits of Delaware law tout the fact that Delaware has low business taxes. This claims is dubious in the case of actively operating big businesses like Mr. Musk's business.

Sales taxes are imposed where cars are sold, not where the seller is incorporated. State sales taxes are allocated to a company based upon where it has sales, where it has assets, and where it has employees, no significant part of which are in Delaware in the case of a big operating business. The Delaware franchise tax is higher than most other state franchise taxes (except California), but this tax is trivial in absolute dollar amounts and is virtually irrelevant in the decision about where to locate a big business.

The tax benefits of a Delaware place of organization are pretty much limited to shell companies and companies with predominantly intangible investment assets. They are virtually irrelevant to an active operating company that makes and sells real world tangible products.

###### There Are No Privacy Benefits To Delaware Law For Big Businesses

Delaware privacy protections are also often touted as a benefit to incorporating in that state. But privacy considerations are likewise irrelevant, because the disclosure requirement that publicly held companies, like Mr. Musk's, are burdened by, arise from federal law and are implemented by the federal Securities Exchange Commission (SEC).

Even if Mr. Musk's company relocated itself, for example, to the Cayman Islands, which is itself outside of U.S. jurisdiction, he would need to make SEC mandated disclosures about is company if the company were listed on U.S. stock exchanges. Certainly, a move from Delaware to Texas wouldn't provide any privacy benefits (or any meaningful privacy harms) to Mr. Musk or his company.

###### Conclusion

When push comes to shove, relocating the company from Delaware to Texas, prospectively, is indeed something that Mr. Must can do if he chooses to do so, despite the downsides of that choice. In the literature of corporate law in the United States, this is called the "[race to the bottom](https://chicagounbound.uchicago.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=&httpsredir=1&article=2161&context=journal_articles)."

Comment: It's 3 orders of magnitude greater than comparable companies, not an order of magnitude.

Comment: @Therac no, Mr. Musk is only producing a lot of hot air when he speaks. In fact, he lied more often than not to the press, shareholders and investors, **especially** in legal matters he told untruths if he wasn't in front of the court. That's the only place he shuts up and that for a good reason: It would be *very* costly..

Comment: So what about moving again from Texas to another state like Florida if a Texan judge rules against him ?

Comment: @mathssoso Same deal. He doesn't escape the ruling in Texas that he doesn't like nor is he better off on any claim that accrued while the company was based in Texas.

Comment: @mathssoso what about it?  Moving to another state only affects suits that happen after the move and only if they concern events that occurred after the move ("A Move To Texas Would Only Have Prospective Effect"). Suppose you live in the town of Delaville, which has an ordinance against lawn ornaments, and you receive a ticket because you refuse to remove your garden gnome.  Can you move to Texton if your court case against the fine fails?  Yes, but it doesn't affect the outcome of the case.

Answer (score 5):

Nothing. He is free to reincorporate in Texas or Florida or California or the Cayman Islands.

That is unlikely to have much effect on his legal liability, though. Although there are limits on the options, the choice of where to sue Tesla generally belongs to the person doing the suing, not to the person being sued.

So he can incorporate wherever he wants, but if his car kills someone in Delaware, he can probably expect a lawsuit in Delaware.

This is a case about corporate governance, though, so Delaware is probably the most proper place for it. But changing the state of incorporation now won't do much to help, because the tortious conduct already occurred in Delaware, and the lawsuit was already filed in Delaware. It's probably too late to force it into another state.